# Why the Helmholtz free energy is minimized when states obey the Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

The Helmholtz free energy is defined by the difference between the internal energy and the entropy of the system,

$$F_{T} = U_{T} + kTH_{T},$$

where $U_{T} = \sum_s P_{T}(s)E(s)$ is the internal energy of a state $s$ and $H_{T} = -\sum_s P_{T}(s) \log P_{T}(s)$ is the entropy. Why $P_{T}(s)$ is the Boltzmann distribution when $F$ is minimized?

I try to minimize $F_{T}$ w.r.t. $P_{T}(s)$ but fail to obtain the Boltzmann distribution.

$$\begin{aligned}
& \frac{d F_{T}}{d P_{T}(s)}= E_{s}-k T \left[\log P_{T}(s) + 1\right] = 0\\
& \Rightarrow E_{s} = k T \left[\log P_{T}(s) + 1\right]\\
& \Rightarrow P_{T}(s) = \exp(\frac{E_{s}}{k T}-1) \quad s.t. \quad \sum_s P_{T}(s) = 1\\
& \Rightarrow P_{T}(s) = \exp \left( \frac{E_{s}}{k T}- \sum_s \exp(\frac{E_{s}}{k T}-1) \right)\\
& \Rightarrow P_{T}(s) = \frac{\exp (\frac{E_{s}}{k T})}{\sum_s \exp(\frac{E_{s}}{k T}-1) }
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The formula for $H$ requires a minus sign. You get the result by minimizing $F$ with respect to $P(s)$ with the constraint that $\sum P(s) = 1$ (use a Lagrange multiplier).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response, @GiorgioP. But I am still stucking in the derivation. Would you please help me with this? Please see my update about the question.

Comment: $H$ needed a minus sign, but you should not change the sign in $F=U-TH$. Moreover, you should impose the normalization constraint. i.e. the quantity to be minimized is $U-TH-\lambda (\sum p_i -1)$. This way, you introduce a constant which will be determined by the condition $\sum p_i=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, but introducing the normalization constraint doesn't help me with the derivation. As shown above, the formulation of $P_{T}(s)$ is not the Boltzmann distribution, and that's what I am confused about. @GiorgioP

Comment: I wrote that you should be careful with signs. If you write the Lagrange multiplier as $\lambda=k_BT \lambda'$ the extremum condition is $E_s+k_BT(\log P_s +1)-k_BT \lambda'=0$. Introducing a new constant $C=e^{1-\lambda'}$ you have the usual Boltzmann distribution once $C$ is obtained from normalization.  However, I would like to bring to your attention that if the *why* in your question refers to this calculation, your question will be closed since it would correspond to a homework-like question, not suitable for this site.

Comment: Unluckily that's true. The question may be silly for a professional researcher like you, but I really do want to know why and I have strived to solve it by myself and failed. It's OK if you don't want to answer this and I am appreciated for your help. @GiorgioP

Comment: Some calculations become easy with experience, but at the beginning, nothing is obvious, and it is not a shame to ask. However, for each problem, there is an optimal tool. This site is great for a conceptual question, but its policy is against homework-like questions, and reading in the Help Center, it is possible to understand the rationale behind it. Take it into account for your next contribution.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. @GiorgioP